# Oracle 11g TNSLSNR LAST_ACK connection flooding

Tags: windows, tcp, oracle

We have Windows 2k3 EE SP2 with Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 DB installed. The DB is used by different applications (including web-apps and services). From time to time, we have some problems with the web application that causes unexpected behavior in it, e.g. slow or not fully loaded pages, strange redirects. Restarting the Tomcat and Oracle services fixes the issue.

Once when the problem showed up again, I looked at the tomcat logs and noticed an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

It occurred to me that the database server may be busy, overloaded or something, so I examined network activity (with CurrPorts). There were dozens of connections hanging with status of "Last Ack" that originated from the Oracle TNSLSNR.exe process, requesting for local port 1521 (which, as we know, is the port that the process *itself* "Listens" to).

The CurrPorts software has the option "Close selected TCP connections" when right-clicking, so I used it for all these dead connections. It immediately fixed the connection issues that the web-app experienced. The worst thing is, this situation recurs, as one or two times an hour a new connection stuck at Last ack appears.

All this means that every couple of days, I have to close these connections manually, as I have neither idea why they happen, nor a solution for now.

So, I am wondering what may the cause be for this?

([Image of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Yea.png))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a picture of the TCP state diagram:

- http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/Tcp_state_diagram_fixed.svg

A system ends up in `LAST_ACK` when it receives a `FIN` and becomes the "passive" closer.

The system's IP stack then responds to that `FIN` with an `ACK` and sets the related socket to `CLOSE_WAIT`.

The application then needs to realise the socket is finished, call `close()` on the socket, then the system's IP stack sends a `FIN` and sets the socket to `LAST_ACK`.

The remote end then needs to respond with an `ACK` and the socket becomes `CLOSED`. This is the step which isn't happening.

I see you're using the local system's IP address as both source and destination. I'm sorry I don't know more about local host communication on Windows. This might be a Windows problem or an Oracle problem. I hope that at least helps you understand *what* is happening, if not *why*.

Comment: I _think_ I understood. I noticed some (maybe related) `CLOSE_WAIT` connections and I am wondering if both sockets of the communication could be performing "Passive" close and if this may be the reason for the problem. I will have to thoroughly search my code for wrong socket close procedures. Thanks for the info!

Comment: No, one side is always the active closer, one side is always the passive closer. The active closer is the one who sends the first FIN. Presumably, the active closer is the end whose application closed its socket first.